# Compiler Type Promotion

Tags: casting, compiler-construction, type-promotion

I am making a compiler as an exercise before applying to jobs, and am working by myself but following a college course website (thus I have already graduated, this is not schoolwork).

Currently, I am unsure how to resolve typecasting with post-fix notation. If I have:

```
"1.0 plus 2 equals" + 1.0 + 2
```

and

```
1+2/(3-4)
```

Then in post fix notation, I can obtain

```
STR[1,0]:"1.0 plus 2 equals"
DBL[1,22]:1.0
INT[1,28]:2
ADD[1,26]:+
ADD[1,20]:+
```

and

```
INT[0,0]:1
INT[0,2]:2
INT[0,5]:3
INT[0,7]:4
SUB[0,6]:-
DIV[0,3]:/
ADD[0,1]:+
```

I am unsure of how to evaluate the first. Currently I have assumed everything to (incorrectly) be doubles and have obtained this code (under Compiler.java):

```
static Object evaluate(List<Token> tokens)
{
    Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (Token token : tokens)
    {
        if (token.isEX())
            stack.push(Double.parseDouble(token.getLexeme()));
        else
        {
            Double a = stack.pop();
            Double b = stack.pop();

            switch (token.getType())
            {
                case ADD:
                    stack.push(b+a);
                    break;
                case SUB:
                    stack.push(b-a);
                    break;
                case MUL:
                    stack.push(b*a);
                    break;
                case DIV:
                    stack.push(b/a);
                    break;
                case MOD:
                    stack.push(b%a);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

I can correctly evaluate the second to -1, but this has two obvious problems, it promotes an integer when it doesn't need to, and it doesn't work for string concatenation.

A direct answer would be nice, but some hints/websites or guides would be greatly appreciated instead.

**Here are the files for understanding this code (though it is generic to many other homemade compilers):**

Compiler.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Compiler
{
    /**
     * Converts code string to direct stack of tokens
     *
     * @param line source of code
     * @param lineNum line number
     * @return stack of tokens in line order
     */
    static Stack<Token> tokenize(String line, int lineNum)
    {
        Stack<Token> tokens = new Stack<>();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Token.regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        while (m.find())
            tokens.push(new Token(m.group(), lineNum, m.start()));

        return tokens;
    }

    /**
     * Formats stack of tokens to postfix notation (Shunting-Yard Algorithm)
     *
     * @param tokens to be added.
     * @return stack tokens in postfix notation
     */
    static Stack<Token> format(Stack<Token> tokens)
    {
        Stack<Token> out = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Token> tmp = new Stack<>();

        for (Token token : tokens)
        {
            Token.Type type = token.getType();

            if (type.rank > 0)  // if token is operation
            {
                while (!tmp.isEmpty() && tmp.peek().getType().rank > type.rank)
                    out.add(tmp.pop());
                tmp.push(token);
            }
            else if (type == Token.Type.LPR)
                tmp.push(token);
            else if (type == Token.Type.RPR)
            {
                while (tmp.peek().getType() != Token.Type.LPR)
                    out.add(tmp.pop());
                tmp.pop();
            }
            else
                out.add(token);
        }

        while (!tmp.isEmpty())
            out.add(tmp.pop());

        return out;
    }

    static Object evaluate(List<Token> tokens)
    {
        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (Token token : tokens)
        {
            if (token.isEX())
                stack.push(Double.parseDouble(token.getLexeme()));
            else
            {
                // TODO: don't just assume it's double here?
                Double a = stack.pop();
                Double b = stack.pop();

                // TODO: only allow add if either token is a string
                switch (token.getType())
                {
                    case ADD:
                        stack.push(b+a);
                        break;
                    case SUB:
                        stack.push(b-a);
                        break;
                    case MUL:
                        stack.push(b*a);
                        break;
                    case DIV:
                        stack.push(b/a);
                        break;
                    case MOD:
                        stack.push(b%a);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Token.java:

```
public class Token
{
    enum Type
    {
        LSH(3, "<<"),       // Left shift
        RSH(3, ">>"),       // Right shift
        MUL(2, "\\*"),      // Multiply
        DIV(2, "/"),        // Divide
        MOD(2, "/"),        // Modulo
        ADD(1, "\\+"),      // Add
        SUB(1, "-"),        // Subtract

        DBL("\\d+\\.\\d*"), // Double
        INT("\\d+"),        // Integer
        STR("\".*\""),      // String
        LPR("\\("),         // Left parenthesis
        RPR("\\)"),         // Right parenthesis
        ;
        //REF(0, "\\w+(\\.\\w+)+"),

        final String symbol;
        final int rank;

        Type(String symbol)
        {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.rank = 0;
        }

        Type(int rank, String symbol)
        {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.rank = rank;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Regular expression for expressions and operations
     */
    final static String regex;

    static
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type[] t = Type.values();
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                sb.append('|');
            sb.append(t[i].symbol);
        }
        regex = sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Text literal
     */
    private String lexeme;

    /**
     * Expression/operation type
     */
    private Type type;

    /**
     * line number
     */
    private int lineNum;

    /**
     * character number
     */
    private int posNum;

    /**
     * Creates a token with debugging information
     *
     * @param lexeme Text literal
     * @param lineNum Line number
     * @param posNum Character number
     * @return Token with processed type of lexeme
     */
    Token(String lexeme, int lineNum, int posNum)
    {
        this.lexeme = lexeme;
        for (Type type : Type.values())
            if (lexeme.matches(type.symbol))
            {
                this.type = type;
                break;
            }
        this.lineNum = lineNum;
        this.posNum = posNum;
    }

    boolean isEX()
    {
        return type.rank == 0;
    }

    boolean isOP()
    {
        return type.rank > 0;
    }

    String getLexeme()
    {
        return lexeme;
    }

    Type getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getLineNum()
    {
        return lineNum;
    }

    public int getPosNum()
    {
        return posNum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s[%d,%d]:%s", type, lineNum, posNum, lexeme);
    }
}
```

Driver.java (for some simple test cases):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String simpleTest = "1+2/(3-4)";
        Stack<Token> tokens;
        tokens = Compiler.format(Compiler.tokenize(simpleTest, 0));
        System.out.println("Simple Test");
        tokens.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(Compiler.evaluate(tokens));

        String hardTest = "\"1.0 plus 2 equals\" + 1.0 + 2";
        tokens = Compiler.format(Compiler.tokenize(hardTest, 1));
        System.out.println("\nHard Test");
        tokens.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: A lightweight approach would be: Maintain a stack of objects, and dispatch not only on the type of the operator but also on the type of the operands. The more heavyweight approach would be to wrap all stack contents into an `Expression` which holds the value and the requirements on the stack. Then write an Evaluator (which is a Visitor, see Visitor-Pattern), which operates on a stack of Expressions and is passed any new operation coming in (instantly transforming the stack). This approach will also have to dispatch on the operand types, yet the switch-case will not be necessary.